# PHP Array_Diff giving nothing back

Tags: php

I am using code below to get the uploadedJSON arrays that are not contained in the localJSON.

```
$uploadedJSON = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'),true);

$data = file_get_contents('results.json');
$localJSON = json_decode($data,true);   

$result = array_diff($uploadedJSON, $localJSON);
```

My uploadedJSON is the following:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [shop] => OTCI
            [iPadNumber] => 1
            [startTime] => 03 03 14
            [endTime] => 04 04 14
            [elapsedTime] => 54
            [amount] => 15
            [receipt] => 0
            [staffID] => 123456789
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [shop] => OTCI
            [iPadNumber] => 1
            [startTime] => 03 03 14
            [endTime] => 04 04 14
            [elapsedTime] => 54
            [amount] => 15
            [receipt] => 1
            [staffID] => 123456789
        )

)
```

My $localJSON is the following:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [shop] => OTCI
            [iPadNumber] => 1
            [startTime] => 03 03 14
            [endTime] => 04 04 14
            [elapsedTime] => 54
            [amount] => 15
            [receipt] => 1111
            [staffID] => 123456789
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [shop] => OTCI
            [iPadNumber] => 1
            [startTime] => 03 03 14
            [endTime] => 04 04 14
            [elapsedTime] => 54
            [amount] => 15
            [receipt] => 2222
            [staffID] => 123456789
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [shop] => OTCI
            [iPadNumber] => 1
            [startTime] => 03 03 14
            [endTime] => 04 04 14
            [elapsedTime] => 54
            [amount] => 15
            [receipt] => 3333
            [staffID] => 123456789
        )

)
```

And the difference is nothing. How can i get the arrays in uploadedJSON that are not contained in localJSON.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

> This function only checks one dimension of a n-dimensional array. Of course you can check deeper dimensions by using array_diff($array1[0], $array2[0]);.

**[SOURCE](http://php.net/array_diff)**

You will most likely need to create a for loop, calling the `array_dif()` method for your two-dimensional array.